# How can I unset a variable in liquid?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

How can I unset a variable in liquid, that has been created via an earlier `{% assign ... %}` statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Liquid, you won't find a command like "unset" that does what you want directly.

However, you can make a variable empty and and effectively non-existent using the value `nil`:

`{% assign foo = nil %}`

In a boolean expression, a variable with the value `nil` is considered `false`.

In the example below Liquid will print nothing:

```
{% assign foo = nil %}
{% if foo %}
  <p>I'm a paragraph.</p>
{% endif %}
```

You can find more info [here](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/basics/types/#nil).

Comment: Thanks! I didn't understand what you meant by "the variable managed with unset does nothing".

Comment: Referring to the Liquid ```assign``` tag which allows you to create and initialize a variable, you cannot destroy a variable using the ```unset``` tag because it does not exist in Liquid. So nowadays, you won't find something like ```{% unset foo %}```.

Comment: Thanks, it was the mention of `unset` in the first place that confused me, especially with the formatting which made me think it was something real. I've edited your answer to make that part clearer, hope it's ok!